# GraphQL Query worked, now returns null;

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql

So I am trying out GraphQL and I've run into a weird issue. The same query that returned data , now returns null. 
I am using a dummy "database" in form of an array 
This issue appeared when I tried to add a new array and type, Authors. I've deleted everything to go back to the initial code and it still wont return the proper data from the array.

schema.js

```js
    const graphql = require('graphql');
    const _ = require('lodash');
    
    
    const {
        GraphQLObjectType,
        GraphQLID,
        GraphQLString,
        GraphQLSchema
    } = graphql;
    
    // dummy data
    var booksarr = [
        {name: 'Name of the Wind', genre: 'Fantasy' , id: 1},
        {name: 'The Final Empire', genre: 'Fantasy' , id: 2},
        {name: 'The Long Earth', genre: 'Sci-Fi' , id: 3}
    ];
    
    
    const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Book',
        fields: () =>({
            id: {type: GraphQLID},
            name: {type: GraphQLString},
            genre: {type: GraphQLString}
        })
    });
    
    
    const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "RootQueryType",
        fields: {
            book: {
                type: BookType,
                args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
                resolve(parent, args){
                    //Get data from db / sources
                    return _.find(booksarr,{id: args.id});
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
        query: RootQuery
    });
```

app.js

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const {graphqlHTTP} = require('express-graphql');
    const schema = require('./schema/schema');
    
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
        schema,
        graphiql: true
    }));
    
    app.listen(8080,() =>{
        console.log("Now listening on port 8080");
    });
```

[image: Image from graphiql]

Answer (score 0):

Your query is passing `ID` as a string, but in `booksarr` the ID is a number. Either your code needs to handle both, or your query needs to pass an integer.

Comment: Shouldnt the ID type accept Int or Strings ? I have passed and Int and it still comes back null.

Comment: `ID` accepts strings and ints, but `_.find` doesn't. If it still doesn't work, then you need to debug your `_.find` code to see what arguments you're getting and see why it's not matching.

Comment: to put it in other words, this will fix it `return _.find(booksarr, { id: Number(args.id) });`

Answer (score -1):

The id in your books list is number type change it to string type and it will work. from 1 to '1'

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893737/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).